# Java multiple keys pressed

Tags: java, animation, user-interface, set, frame

I'm trying to move a ball across a frame. I have the up, down, left, and right motion going fine. But when I try to move diagonally, it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code.

First I declare some sets; pressed is the keys pressed, and the others are combinations of keys to move the ball up and left so on so forth;

```
public Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<>();
public Set<Integer> upLeft, upRight, downLeft, downRight;
```

Next, in my init method I start to add the integer values to the sets and add key listeners to my frame:

```
private void myInit(){
        ... // cut down code from above
        int[] a = new int[2];
        a[0] = 38; a[1] = 37;
            upLeft = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(a));
        a[1] = 39;
            upRight = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(a));
        a[0] = 40; a[1] = 37;
            downLeft = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(a));
        a[1] = 39;
            downRight = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(a));

        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now here are my methods to handle the key pressed and released:

```
public synchronized void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        pressed.add(evt.getKeyCode());
        System.out.println("Added:"+evt.getKeyCode());

        if(pressed.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Size is 1");
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_UP) {
                if(y <= 25) {
                    y = 25;
                }
                else  {
                    y = y - yUpSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_DOWN) {
                if(y >= (500-25)) {
                    y = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    y = y + yDownSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_LEFT) {
                if(x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                }
                else {
                    x = x - xLeftSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_RIGHT) {
                if(x >= (500-25)) {
                    x = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    x = x + xRightSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        else if(pressed.size() == 2) {
            System.out.println("Size is 2");
            if(pressed.containsAll(upLeft)) {
                if(y <= 25) {
                    y = 25;
                }
                else  {
                    y = y - yUpSpeed;
                }
                if(x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                }
                else {
                    x = x - xLeftSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(pressed.containsAll(upRight)) {
                if(y <= 25) {
                    y = 25;
                }
                else  {
                    y = y - yUpSpeed;
                }
                if(x >= (500-25)) {
                    x = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    x = x + xRightSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(pressed.containsAll(downLeft)) {
                if(y >= (500-25)) {
                    y = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    y = y + yDownSpeed;
                }
                if(x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                }
                else {
                    x = x - xLeftSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(pressed.containsAll(downRight)) {
                if(y >= (500-25)) {
                    y = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    y = y + yDownSpeed;
                }
                if(x >= (500-25)) {
                    x = (500-25);
                }
                else {
                    x = x + xRightSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Size is more than 2");
        }

    public synchronized void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
            System.out.println("Removed:"+evt.getKeyCode());
            pressed.remove(evt.getKeyCode());
        }
```

The problem is that, from the debug system.out messages, the size of the set pressed is never larger than one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused, so basically, when a key is pressed, check what key it was and it to the list, when released, remove it from the list, then use done kind of update loop to check what's in the list and update the state of the ball

Comment: @MadProgrammer basically yes. When key is pressed, add it to the list, then depending on if one or multiple keys were pressed, update position of ball. Then when key is released, remove it from list.

Comment: Good, so remove the movement logic from key event handler methods

Comment: You should get two keypressed events; one for each key pressed. Does your logic work, if they come one at a time back to back?

Comment: @SteveHarrington the problem is, I only get one

Comment: When I press and hold one key, doesn't matter which, the ball moves in that direction. When I then press another key (now pressing two down), the ball switches to that new direction without changing the size of the pressed set.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think the problem is that even if I quickly press two arrow keys at the same time, one is still getting pressed faster than the other. So, the programs reads it as only having one key pressed and it gets stuck inside the if loop for only one key pressed.

Comment: This is why you don't want your logic in the event handler

Comment: @MadProgrammer What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you do get multiple keypressed events, but the second "overrides" the first (in terms of your logic for movement). @MadProgrammer's suggestion sounds good then.

Comment: @SteveHarrington I'll be honest. I'm quite new to this animation stuff in java. I've seen some tutorials on line for basic movement, but nothing for handling multiple key events at the same time. You guys are saying that my logic is not the best, how can I improve the logic. Can you guys post a couple lines of code explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `KeyBoardAnimation` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). It keeps a `Map` of the keys that are currently pressed and then move the object based on all the keys in the `Map`.

This approach uses `Key Bindings`, which is preferred over a KeyListener for the reasons given in the blog.